# Transform custom Json (object) in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I need help with this JSON.
I need to transform a json into the array format below, the problem is that a children property can have infinite generation, does anyone know how to do this?
I can't imagine how to loop this Json
The interface example is:

````
`interface User {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  children?: any;
  level: number;
}`


``` {
  '0': {
    id: '2469bdab-23b5-4cb8-90c9-c609a49410b0',
    name: 'Richard Paul M.',
    children: {
      '0': {
        id: '97cd3a19-0f1c-4248-a84c-a1f5a0093a89',
        name: 'Luis F. Doris',
        children: {
          '0': {
            id: '6410eff5-5aff-46fd-bb08-ed90581007b4',
            name: 'Maurice Rudolf Ludwig',
            children: {
              '0': {
                id: '35996ee4-74a6-4343-ba5e-9700c24bee11',
                name: 'Joseph E. James A.',
                children: {
                  '0': {
                    id: '59fdebaf-0229-4d27-901d-4cfbb4cf81de',
                    name: 'Alan G. William',
                    children: {},
                    level: 4
                  }
                },
                level: 3
              ......
```
````

Comment: First you should parse the JSON with `JSON.parse`. Probably you have to fix the format. Your JSON isn't valid. Keys and strings have to be double quoted in JSON. Then you can convert the object to an array with `Object.values`.

Comment: Do you mean `children: User[];` instead of `children?: any;`?

Comment: Yes, children: User[];

Comment: First step should be to fix the JSON. It's not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recursively transform your object into an array, simple enough to do:

```
interface User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    children?: User[];
    level: number;
}

const getUser = (user: User) => {
    const result: User = {
        id: user.id,
        name: user.name,
        level: user.level,
    };
    if (user.children) {
        result.children = Object.keys(user.children).map(key => getUser(user.children[key]));
    }

    return result;
};

const inputJson = {}; // Your input object here;

const endResult = Object.keys(inputJson).map(key => getUser(inputJson[key]));
```